# Python Parse XML to JSON

Tags: python, json, xml

I am currently working with some *interesting* XML string responses. Essentially, the XML I'm receiving is nested, but it reads like a CSV file.  Example:

```
xml = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<ThisDocument protocol="OCI" xmlns="C" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<sessionId xmlns="">29348u29!!4nthisSucks!==</sessionId>
  <command echo="" xsi:type="GroupGetListInServiceProviderResponse" xmlns="">
    <groupTable>
      <colHeading>Group Id</colHeading>
      <colHeading>Group Name</colHeading>
      <colHeading>User Limit</colHeading>
      <row>
        <col>LRB7905</col>
        <col>Test1</col>
        <col>25</col>
      </row>
      <row>
        <col>LRB9294</col>
        <col>Test2</col>
        <col>100</col>
      </row>
      <row>
        <col>LRB8270</col>
        <col>Test3</col>
        <col>10</col>
      </row>
      <row>
        <col>LRB8212</col>
        <col>Test4</col>
        <col>25</col>
      </row>
      <row>
        <col>LRB8175</col>
        <col>Test5</col>
        <col>25</col>
      </row>
    </groupTable>
  </command>
</ThisDocument>
```

In the responses I receive from the server in question, the 'colHeading' is the 'key' for and the 'col' for each 'row' corresponds to the value.  It seems like an easy structure to map, but I cannot think of a 'PYTHONIC' way to perform this task.  The desired outcome is:

```
{
  "groupTable": [
    {
        "Group ID": "LRB7905",
        "Group Name": "Test1",
        "User Limit": "25"
    },
    {
        "Group ID": "LRB9294",
        "Group Name": "Test2",
        "User Limit": "100"
    },
    {
        "Group ID": "LRB8270",
        "Group Name": "Test3",
        "User Limit": "10"
    },
    {
        "Group ID": "LRB8212",
        "Group Name": "Test4",
        "User Limit": "25"
    },
    {
        "Group ID": "LRB8175",
        "Group Name": "Test5",
        "User Limit": "25"
    }
  ]
}
```

The information I really need is contained in the 'col' fields of the XML, and the number of colHeadings corresponds to the number of values in each 'row'.  So far, I've been able to manipulate the values into CSV files, but ultimately, I need to create JSON objects (dicts) with the key, value pairs.  I've used different libraries/modules etc... but the best approach I've come up with, is to break the colHeadings and Values into two lists, and then combine them.

Code so far:

```
xmlroot = ET.fromstring(xml)

headings =[]
values = []

def breakoutLists(xmlroot):
    for columnHeading in root.iter('colHeading'):
        headings.append(columnHeading.text)
    for column in root.iter('col'):
        values.append(column.text)
    return headings, values

breakoutLists(xmlroot)

zipped = dict(itertools.izip(values, itertools.cycle(headings)))
print zipped
```

This produces a dictionary, but the in the order of `values: keys` instead of `keys: values`.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on the best way to approach this task.
Thanks in advance!!!

**EDIT** Thanks to the help of Eric, I was able to accomplish my goal!

```
groupResp = {'groupResponse': []}    
def breakoutLists(root):
    headings = [h.text for h in root.iter('colHeading')]

    return (
        {
            h: col.text
            for h, col in zip(headings, row.iter('col'))
        }
        for row in root.iter('row')
    )

data = list(breakoutLists(root))

for item in data:
    groupResp['groupResponse'].append(item)

print json.dumps(groupResp)
```

I can probably clean this up a bit to append the dictionary during the initial function, but I'm good for now!

Comment: `zipped = dict(itertools.izip(itertools.cycle(headings), values ))` instead of `zipped = dict(itertools.izip(values, itertools.cycle(headings)))` ? About .izip () : # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy

Comment: @SerCrAsH: Was my first thought, but doesn't work, because of `cycle` - note that that builds a `dict`, but he wants a `list<dict>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code flattens the data, which is unhelful - you need to iterate over the row objects

```
def breakoutLists(xmlroot):
    headings = [h.text for h in root.iter('colHeading')]

    return (
        {
            h: col.text
            for h, col in zip(headings, row.iter('column'))
        }
        for row in root.iter('row')
    )

data = list(breakoutLists(html))
```

Comment: Thank you so very much!  That helped me greatly... I had gotten somewhat close using a for loop before, but abandoned it because I couldn't manipulate the data correctly. With your help and a few more lines, I was able to accomplish my goal: